# Why can't I use std::string with libcurl?

Tags: c++, string, curl

I'm trying to make a very simple program that request a few pages, here is my code so far:

```
string fUrl = "http://google.com/";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        char const* chFUrl = fUrl.c_str();
        //char const chFUrl[] = "http://google.com/";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, chFUrl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        cout << chFUrl << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, notice that I'm trying to passa fUrl.c_str() to curl, but nothing happens, it simply skip through the curl functions, print the url and pause.
If I comment out thar line, and uncomment the "char const chFUrl[]...", everything works just fine and curl output the html response to the terminal.

When I run through the fUrl.c_str() and it doesn't work, nothing is printed to the console on VS. I have very little experience with C++, so any ideas is appreciated.

--Edit:
I just tested this code:

```
char const chFUrl[] = "http://google.com";
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(chFUrl); i++) {
    cout << chFUrl[i] << endl;
}
```

And it output the whole url to the terminal, however, when I use this:

```
char const* chFUrl = fUrl.c_str();
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(chFUrl); i++) {
    cout << chFUrl[i] << endl;
}
```

It only outputs "http", even tough if I cout chFUrl[4] I get the ":".

Comment: Have you tried declaring and initializing `fUrl` inside `main`?

Comment: Looking at [this documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) it says that the third parameter to `curl_easy_setopt()` "can be a long, a function pointer, an object pointer or a curl_off_t". You are passing a string. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Please provide a **complete** sample program so that we can reproduce your results. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.  [This program](http://ideone.com/m69hs7), for example, works perfectly for me on Ubuntu 13.04. That is, when I run it, it displays the contents of the google front page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your third snippet. `sizeof(chFUrl)` will return the sizeof pointer. It's a `const char*` and not a `const char` array. You should make it correct by substituting it with `fUrl.size()`.